# writing a json object to .json file using javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, json

I need to write a json object to a .json file using javascript and php. The json object seems to be storing the values correctly, but the php file doesn't seem to run so nothing happens.

Thanks.

my javascript function, which is called on a button click:

```
    function save_crime()
{
    //json object, v1, v2, v3 etc are variables whose values are set in a different function
    var jsonObject = { "crime" : {  "violence" : {  "violence1" : v1,
                                                    "violence2" : v2,
                                                    "violence3" : v3
                                    },

                                    "burglary" : {  "burglary1" : b1,
                                                    "burglary2" : b2
                                    },

                                    "robbery" :  {  "robbery1" : r1,
                                                    "robbery2" : r2
                                    },

                                    "criminal" : {  "criminal1" : c1,
                                                    "criminal2" : c2,
                                                "criminal3" : c3
                                    } 
                                } 
                    }



    //jQuery to post json object to json.php for writing to json file
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : 'json.php',
        dataType : 'json', 
        data : {
            json : JSON.stringify(jsonObject)
        }
    });

}
```

php file for writing to .json file:

```
<?php

$json = $_POST['json'];
$info = json_encode($json);

$file = "crimes.json";
$handle = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($handle, $info);
fclose($handle);

?>
```

Comment: [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) encodes an array. Maybe you need to decode first what you receieve from the ajax request?

Comment: Try adding success and error callback functions to the .ajax call.  They should give you more info on what's happening when it tries to call the PHP file.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing the **JSON string** to a file, you dont need to decode as its a string already from JS part (`JSON.stringify(jsonObject)`).

Just write it directly.

```
file_put_contents("crimes.json",  $_POST['json']);
```

Its better to get a response from server so that you know the action is performed properly. Use the `$.post` shorthand instead of `$.ajax`.

```
$.post(
    'json.php',
    {
        json : JSON.stringify(jsonObject)
    },
    function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    }
);
```

Comment: I tried the file_put_contents method, it still doesn't appear to be doing anything though.

Comment: @user1269902 How are you sure that its not doing anything?  *what* its not doing?

Comment: creating the crimes.json file

Comment: create the file on a directory where you can write. for example `/tmp`

Comment: That didn't work either. I think there is something wrong with my javascript function.

Comment: Try using `$.post` the way I shown in the answer (updated). And return  some status from `json.php` file so that you can catch the status on the callback function and check if everything is working properly.

Comment: BTW, what the ajax response you see in the firebug or chrome console?

Comment: the problem was in the <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script> thanks for your help

Comment: '$ is not defined' means you haven't included jQuery. Include it